# Put Days of The Week On Graph, Charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I'm using Charts to display a bar graph but, I cannot get the x-Axis to print out with the days of the week instead of: 0,1,2,3, etc.

Initializing chart:

```
var weekdays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

func initializeChart() {
    chartView.noDataText = "No Data"
    chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)
    chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
     chartView.chartDescription.text = "Revenue"

    //chartView.xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0)

    chartView.legend.enabled = false
    chartView.scaleYEnabled = false
    chartView.scaleXEnabled = false
    chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false

    chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
    chartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100.00
    chartView.highlighter = nil
    chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
}
```

This is the data I'm populating:

```
if json != nil {
    let week = json["week"]
    let month = json["month"]
    print("Check", week, month)

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<self.weekdays.count {
        let day = self.weekdays[i]
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: [(week[day].double)!])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        print("data entry", dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Weekdays")
    chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

    self.chartView.data = chartData
}
```

I just want to print the days of the week on the x-Axis. Could you help?

Comment: Have you configured value formatter for x-axis? If not try to set it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set valueFormatter for X-axis, try this code. hope it helps!

```
if json != nil {
let week = json["week"]
let month = json["month"]
print("Check", week, month)

var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

for i in 0..<self.weekdays.count {
    let day = self.weekdays[i]
    let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: 
[(week[day].double)!] , data: weekdays as AnyObject?))
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    print("data entry", dataEntry)
}

let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Weekdays")
    chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    let xAxisValue = chartView.xAxis
    xAxisValue.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
    self.chartView.data = chartData
}

extension DemoBaseViewController: IAxisValueFormatter {

func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
return weekdays[Int(value)]
}
}
```